# How to program the tunnels in a Dig Dug demake?

Tags: arcade, pico-8

I'm trying to remake Dig Dug and am struggling when it comes to how to make the tunnels. I'm actually attempting to demake it on Pico8. I'm relatively new to Pico8 but not new to game development.
I'm thinking I might try to just save the locations of tunnels in a table that I can read and write to, but even that I'm just not sure of the best way to make that work.
Does anyone have some ideas? Please explain them, as I'm still pretty new to working with Pico8.

Comment: Not all people have played the game Dig Dug. Please edit your question and add a screenshot from the game, showing how a typical tunnel can look like.

Comment: How have you attempted your table-based solution so far, and where specifically did you get stuck?